# How to use python Transaction without database ?

Tags: python

I have two line in my code which first one is `os.unlink` and second one is `os.symlink`. like :

```
os.unlink(path)
os.symlink(new_path)
```

The sequence should not be change, The problem is, some times it unlink a file (in other word it remove it's shortcut) but second line could not create symbolic link (do to some addressing issue).

My question is: Is there any all or non transaction tool like the one we have in database, to do both line or non ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
import os

linkname = '/tmp/test.lnk'
orig_target = os.path.realpath(linkname)
os.unlink(linkname)
try:
    os.symlink(new_target, linkname)
except:
    os.symlink(orig_target, linkname)
```

maybe check what exceptions can occur and only catch the ones that are relevant.

Comment: the problem is it don't create exception part, because of some addressing issue.it do't create symbolic link unless the address exist.

Comment: so checking first whether the new target exists would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it is not possible unless you use *Transactional filesystem* like *TxF* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) because nothing prevents your machine from poweroff between two commands.

I can see 2 ways here:

1) Switch to Database

2) Check all conditions *before* unlinking. What prevents you from symlinking?